# Electron/React + MRT Table cannot change TextField value after row deletion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, electron, material-react-table

I have weird problem.
I am using React on top of electron with MRT Table.
I have 4 tables in total. 1 allows users to edit and delete rows. second allows adding rows to the first one.
[image]

Problem occurs when in export table i delete any of the rows.
(no errors in console is returned).
When i try to edit any of the row in export table the quantity field becomes unclickable for like 30-40 seconds unless I change size of debuger console atleast by 1 pixel or chose this field from debug tools by its div. (SELECT FIELD WORKS NORMALLY WITHOUT ISSUES) (no useeffect is going in the background)  [image]

And on top of that field quantity in the other table becomes unclickable too. (Both of them seem to be Textfield from MUI and It's like all TextFields gets locked ?!?)

The weirdest thing for me is that if i change this textfield to type="number" and i click the arrows (despite being it unclickable) it works perfectly fine, it updates values and if i try to edit rows or add new ones, the new value is taken into consideration not the one that it got locked on.

This is code from upper table of the field Quantity :

```
<TextField
        label="Quantity"
        type="number"
        value={quantity}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setQuantity(event.target.value);
        }}
        sx={{ width: 100, height: 40 }}
      />
```

And this is code from the field on edit function from MRT :
definition of field :

```
 {
  accessorKey: 'quantity',
  header: 'Quantity',
  columnFilterModeOptions: ['contains'],
  enableEditing: true,
  filterFn: 'contains',
  size: 40,
  muiTableBodyCellEditTextFieldProps: {
    type: 'number',
  },
},
```

and code of delete function

```
const handleDeleteRow = useCallback(
(row) => {
  if (
    !confirm(
      `Are you sure you want to delete ${row.getValue(
        'mElnr'
      )} - ${row.getValue('sElnr')} connection ?`
    )
  ) {
    return;
  }
  tableData.splice(row.index, 1);
  setTableData([...tableData]);
},
[tableData]
```

);